# MSXML2.XMLHTTP not working in company network

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, msxml

I've built a macro for a client that POSTs some data to an external URL which requires basic authentication (get/save data in cloud database via api). When I'm running the macro from home (or basically anywhere) it works perfectly. However, when my client runs it (while in his company network), he gets a timeout error message after a few seconds. Any suggestions on what the cause could be?

**Here is my code:**

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
With objHTTP
  .Open "POST", url, False
  .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
  .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
  .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
  .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64EncodeString(apiKey + ":" + apiPw)
  .Send (data)
End With
```

Comment: Could be almost anything.  Seems likely that this company is using a proxy server or something that blocks certain lists of URLs.

Comment: Yes, that was it! They used a proxy server. I included the .setproxy and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks.